# Do electric cars need friction brakes to stop really fast?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, friction, everyday-life

If regenerative braking can't stop an electric car fast enough, can't we actively slow it down by applying a reversed voltage to the DC motor?

**EDIT:** By really fast, I mean in emergency situations where you are about to hit something or someone and want to stop as fast as possible.

Comment: Sounds risky. Would you try to slow down a normal car by throwing it into reverse gear?

Comment: @PM2Ring Isn't there a huge difference between an electric car and normal car though?

Comment: reversing the current may indeed stop the axle/wheel but that does not necessarily stop the car, it may still slide on the road that may have worse consequences

Comment: @hyportnex yes but that's true for friction brakes as well.

Comment: @PM2Ring, But that's what "regenerative braking" actually means. Q: How do you tell whether an electric machine is acting as a motor or as a generator? A: If the shaft is turning in the same direction that the applied voltage wants it to go, then it's acting as a motor. If the shaft is turning in the opposite direction, then it's acting as a generator.

Comment: You need to specify what "really fast" means. The more current your motor and batteries and control electronics can handle, the more torque it can apply to the wheels, the greater the acceleration (in either direction) it can produce. _Practical_ electric cars have friction brakes, but there's more than one reason for that.

Comment: @besmirched, I updated it. Since you seem to know a thing or two, can you provide an answer where you state the feasibility of regenerative braking and why it isn't used in all situations? And I think there is a distinction worth making here about regenerative braking: one when the car free rolls and one when we actively try to produce a counter torque.

Comment: Don't know a lot. I've written some code to control electric motors, but mostly higher-level code--not so much concerned with PWM waveforms or the relationship between current, voltage, torque, and speed. 3rd-party motor controller assembly took care of that. My _guess_ is, a road-worthy car must have friction brakes anyway—for legal reasons, and for practical reasons like parking or, not wanting to consume electric power to hold the vehicle at a stop light. Adding "regen" capability to the motor and charge controllers is extra cost, and not strictly necessary if you have mechanical brakes.

Answer (score 1):

reversing the voltage to the motor while it is running in the opposite direction *is* regenerative braking. And friction brakes are necessary in electric cars, both to hold them in position while parked and also to hold them in position when stopped on a slope.

Comment: Holding them in position while stopped is a good point. But do we only use regenerative braking for an electric car that's moving? I mean, if we want to stop really fast without friction brakes, don't we need to actively apply reversed motor torque?

Comment: yes, but that's exactly the case when you're running the motor voltage backwards. The motor becomes a generator, and pushes electricity back into the battery against the battery voltage.

Comment: I think there are two cases here. One case where we stop supplying current from the battery and just let the current from the back-emf charge the battery. The other case is where we reverse the voltage lines between the battery and motor to supply extra current in the opposite direction to create extra negative torque. I think the first case is pure regenerative braking, while the second case is something else.

Answer (score 1):

> Do electric cars need friction brakes to stop really fast?

It depends on how fast you're already travelling. Regenerative braking is not as effective as conventional braking methods like friction-based braking at lower speeds. The efficiency of regenerative braking increases with increase in speed whereas it remains fairly constant for friction-based braking.

As you say, we can produce an opposite torque by reversing the polarity of the DC motor to bring it to a stop. But there is always a danger of burning the coils of the motor due to the high surge in the reverse current as the applied current reinforces the induced current. There must be some kind of electronic controllers to limit the current in the coils to prevent such events.

Friction-based braking is effective but it comes at the cost of rubbing mechanical parts which would need regular maintenance or replacement. Regenerative braking can store the energy in useful forms (which can be used later) other than simply dissipating it as heat.  I feel the good way to bring a moving electric car to rest is using more regenerative braking (and less friction-based braking) at higher speeds and more friction-based braking  (and less regenerative braking) at lower speeds.

Comment: Is regenerative braking effective enough to be used in most cases on a real world electric car? Is reverse voltage practical enough to be used in real cars or do we still rely on friction brakes to slow the car's speed in certain cases?

Comment: @user2251965: Regenerative braking is definitely used in electric cars as these have a significant impact on the range. The energy that friction-based braking dissipates as heat is stored in the batteries or capacitors (in regenerative braking) which could be used later. I don't know about the practical usage of applying a "reverse voltage" due to the reason mentioned in my answer. However, friction brakes become handy at low speeds and also for parking.

Comment: Basically you're saying, that the motor can stop the car "fast enough" if the electronics can supply/handle "enough" current. And that's all true, but it leaves off any definition of what "enough" means.

Comment: @besmirched: That "enough" depends on how much maximum current the motor or the electronics can support. I don't have any data to support what maximum reverse voltage can be applied to safely bring the car to rest.

Answer (score 0):

Let me first go over some necessary background knowledge.

Today's cars have anti-lock braking. If the brakes do lock the wheels stops rolling, which gives significant loss of grip, in many cases catastrofic loss of grip.

About the amount of power that an electric propulsion system can bring to the wheels:
With a high-performance electric car, when the safety features are disabled, hitting the accelerator hard results in a burn-out. Of course, with standard settings the car will dutifully maintain traction control.

Presumably you can put a driving car in reverse and then send maximum power to the wheels. I assume that would result in the wheels spinning backwards, with catastrofic loss of grip.

**How much power the battery pack can absorb**

Generally the limiting factor to how hard you can brake using purely regenerative braking is how much power the battery pack can absorb. If the battery pack is very large, hence a large overall capacity, the power generated by the regenerative braking can be distributed over a comparatively large amount of battery cells.

If you exceed the rate of current that the battery pack can absorb then the battery suffers irreversible damage. Therefore when you make an electric car brake as hard as possible the regenerative braking is always supplemented with friction braking by the friction brakes.

**Dependence on temperature**

A cold battery pack has much less capacity to absorb current from regenerative braking. To absorb the power atoms must migrate through a fluid. The lower the temperature of that fluid the slower that migration rate.

For the batteries: the process of delivering power generates a bit of heat in the battery. Once the battery has reached optimum working temperature the battery management system starts maintaining that temperature.

Comment: Why don't we dissipate the energy somewhere else? E.g. a large resistor, the car chassis itself.